# Is my syntax for java exponentiation wrong?

Tags: java, math

I am trying to calculate the area of a triangle using Heron's formula, but I think I'm doing something wrong in the `Math.pow` function because as soon as I add it, my print statements no longer work and the program fails to compile. This is what I have:

```java
public class Challenge
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        double a;

        a = triangleArea(3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println("A triangle with sides 3,3,3 has an area of:" + a);

        a = triangleArea(3, 4, 5);
        System.out.println("A triangle with sides 3,4,5 has an area of:" + a);

        a = triangleArea(9, 9, 9);
        System.out.println("A triangle with sides 9,9,9 has an area of:" + a );
    }

    public static double triangleArea( int a, int b, int c )
    {
        double area;
        double s = (a+b+c)/2;
        s= (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5) // this line has the error
        return area;
    }
}
```

The compiler lists the following errors:

```
Challenge.java:22: error: '.class' expected
        area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5) // this line has the error
                              ^
Challenge.java:22: error: ';' expected
        area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5) // this line has the error
                               ^
Challenge.java:22: error: ';' expected
        area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5) // this line has the error
                                           ^
3 errors
```

What do these errors mean?  How do I fix them?

Comment: **What error do you get?**

Comment: `area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5)` ... WTF?. You mean `area= Math.pow(s, b);`? And what's that `=.5` suppose to mean?

Comment: Don't just invent syntax.  Use Java's.

Comment: I was just trying to fix old questions in order to get my question asking privileges back and I thought I was doing that by fixing one of my old stupid questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

> ```
> area= Math.pow(double s,double b=.5)
> ```

should be something like,

```
area = Math.pow(s,0.5);
return area;
```